# CS0016 using dotnet build/publish with --output parameter when running in Server Core Docker EE container

Tags: .net, windows, docker, .net-core

I have a Windows docker container running on Server Core with Docker EE. When I try and run `dotnet build` or `dotnet publish`, I get a CS0016 'Could not write to output file' error.

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY nuget.config ./
COPY API.Core/*.csproj ./API.Core/
COPY API.Core.Service/*.csproj ./API.Core.Service/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish API.Core/API.Core.csproj -c release -o /app --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.Core.dll"]
```

Running interactively inside the container, I can see all of the source files are in C:\src

```
dotnet publish API.Core/API.Core.csproj -c release --output /app
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0+57a23d249 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
CSC : error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'C:\src\API.Core.Service\xmldocs.xml' -- 'Access to the path 'C:\
src\API.Core.Service\xmldocs.xml' is denied.' [C:\src\API.Core.Service\API.Core.Service.csproj]
```

What I find odd is that the path to the 'output file' isn't C:\app\API.Core.Service\xmldocs.xml - it's as if the `--output` parameter is being ignored.

Things I've tried:

- Using dotnet build instead of dotnet publish
- Using an absolute path - C:\app instead of /app
- Removing the output parameter, which should then default to (projectDir)/bin
- Verifying the C:\app directory exists
- Verifying C:\src\API.Core.Service\xmldocs.xml exists
- Running build/publish against the .sln file

Building the Dockerfile and running the container works fine on my laptop running Docker Desktop.

Is the error message misleading and 'output file' is really the source file?

Most of this is copied and tweaked from the MS docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

In the Docker configuration, you are changing the directory from `WORKDIR /app` to `WORKDIR /src` while publishing the code to /app. Change the Docker file to get it work:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.sln ./
COPY nuget.config ./
COPY API.Core/*.csproj ./API.Core/
COPY API.Core.Service/*.csproj ./API.Core.Service/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish API.Core/API.Core.csproj -c release -o /app --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.Core.dll"]
```

Comment: Same problem. I'm intentionally changing working directories to 'src' to keep the source and the publish artifacts separate from each other.